# Best way to have a JTable populate with objects?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable

Let's say I have an array of `People`. These people have a bunch of fields like name, position, title, salary.

I've seen most questions be about filling a `JTable` with 2D arrays which, unless I'm wrong, isn't exactly what I'm trying to do.

I would like to be able to click a button and have the `JTable` look at the array of People and display that table.

Thanks!

Edit: I'm hoping to be able to just change the setModel arguments here to update using certain values.

```
JButton btnRefresh = new JButton("Refresh");
    btnRefresh.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            table_1.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][] {}, new String[] {
                    "#", "Song", "Artist", "Time" }));
            table_1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(22);
            table_1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(191);
            table_1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(179);
            panel_3.revalidate();
        }
    });
```

So I'm able to change the column headers by changing these string values but what can I change the `new Object[][]{}` to?

Comment: Read the JTable tutorial, especially the part about defining your own table model by extending AbstractTableModel. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Comment: So I had seen that documentation a couple of hours ago but it looked a little complicated. If that's the easiest way than I guess I'll look into it but I was hoping to use something related to the edit I just put up.

Comment: Don't use mouse listeners to react to button clicks. A button can be clicked with the keyboard. Use an ActionListener. Defining an subclass of AbstractListener is not hard at all. But you have to try.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that? It just waits for the user to hit the refresh button in the gui and then refreshes the table? (hopefully)

Comment: The proper, documented way to listen to clicks of a button is to add an ActionListener (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html). This will work whether the user clicks the button with his mouse, or with a keyboard shortcut, or by pressing the spacebar/enter while the button has the focus. I guess you already have clicked a button with the keyboard, haven't you? Using a MouseListener will not let the user use his keyboard, which will make him mad at you.

Comment: +1 JB Nizet.Take a look on defining custom table models. Its best way I know

Comment: @JB I think I get what you're saying. But if I don't specify a shortcut than the only option is mouse clicking anyways correct? The thing is I'm not an expert on working with GUI elements so all my buttons have blank action listeners and then mouse listeners under them. So can I just copy the mouse listener code into the respective action listener and it will work fine?

Comment: No. When the button has the focus, it can be clicked with enter or the space bar. And yes, the only difference is that you just need to implement an ActionListener, which will do the exact same thing as the mouse listener. Just as explained in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code fragment does exactly what I needed it to do.

```
JButton btnRefresh = new JButton("Refresh");
        btnRefresh.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(dataArray(),
                        new String[] { "first", "second", "third", "fourth" }));//Changes the column headers
                panel.revalidate();
            }
            private Object[][] dataArray() {
                Object[][] table = new Object[5][4];//5 = rows 4 = columns
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    for(int j = 0; j< 4; j++){                  
                            if(j == 0){
                                table[i][j] = i+1;
                            }else if(j== 1){
                                table[i][j] = "Second Row";//Change these strings to whatever variable you want to fill the second row with, same with the other 3.
                            }else if(j== 2){
                                table[i][j] = "Third Row";
                            }else{
                                table[i][j] = "Fourth Row";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                return table;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Why would you add a MouseListener to a button. You should be using a ActionListener